# Node build failed with babel throws an Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0"

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to build node app with babel but it throws an error.

> Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". If you
>   are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely
>   that something in your build process is loading the wrong version.
>   Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that
>   doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling
>   Babel.

```
at throwVersionError (E:\mern-master\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:65:11)
at Object.assertVersion (E:\mern-master\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
at _default (E:\mern-master\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:41:7)
at E:\mern-master\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
at Function.memoisePluginContainer (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:113:13)
at Function.normalisePlugin (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:146:32)
at C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:184:30
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Function.normalisePlugins (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
at File.initOptions (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
at new File (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
at Pipeline.transform (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
at transform (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\util.js:50:22)
at Object.compile (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\util.js:59:12)
at write (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:21:21)
at handleFile (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:43:7)
at C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:61:9
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at handle (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:59:29)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\dir.js:69:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\index.js:129:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern-ecommerce@1.0.0 build: `mkdir build && babel server/ -d build/server --ignore ./server-entry.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mern-ecommerce@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PranayKumar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-22T18_07_48_781Z-debug.log

Below are my files.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ./pm2-prod.json",
    "build": "mkdir build && babel src/server/ -d build/server --ignore ./src/server/server-entry.js",
    "server": "pm2 start ./pm2-dev.json --no-daemon",
    "build-webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.client.js",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.client.js --open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5"
  }
```

**server-side.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

**server-entry.js**

```
require('@babel/register');
require('./server.js');
```

Comment: The error message says that the stack trace is important, but you've left it out of your post. Without it, this is very hard to answer.

Comment: I just added rest of the error which I see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As shown in the stack trace, Babel is being called via `babel-cli`, which is a problem because `babel-cli` is the Babel 6.x CLI. You also don't have `babel-cli` anywhere in your `devDependencies` list.

For Babel 7, you'll want to:

- install `@babel/cli`
- make sure that you remove any installed `babel-cli` version that is already there
- Make sure you're actually compiling your files with the `babel` command from your local project, not a globally-installed version.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!! I was having a really hard time with this error.

Comment: Correct answer. Remember Babel 6.x uses babel-* prefix for its modules while Babel 7.x moved to @babel/* format for its dependencies